Sonar for gradle project with multiple modules and tests in only one
I'm having this structure:
project

common (module)


common-A (submodule of common)






src/main (no tests)






common-B (submodule of common)






src/main (no tests)





src

main (classes here use the classes from common)
test (tests for classes in main, touching coverage on common modules as well)

in src the classes from the common modules are used and well tested. I am using gradle for my project but I seem to struggle making sonar to see the coverage on files from common-A/src and common-B/src. Any idea or approach here, please?
I have tried to merge them somehow in gradle but it still fails.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
